# Better definition of 'Observatory' that includes modern usage

Tags: meaning, contemporary-english

Commonly when we hear 'observatory' we probably think of an [*astronomical* observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observatory#Astronomical_observatories). Merriam-Webster [defines 'observatory'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/observatory) as:

> 1. a building or place given over to or equipped for observation of
>    **natural phenomena** (as in astronomy) also : an institution whose
>    primary purpose is making such observations
> 2. a situation or structure commanding a wide view

...so there are non-astronomical natural-phenomena observatories - like [*volcano* observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcano_observatory) (*"provides continuous and periodic monitoring of the seismicity, other geophysical changes, ground movements, volcanic gas chemistry,"* etc), but there are now many modern-day usages that don't fit into the dictionary definition:

- [SSL Observatory](https://www.eff.org/observatory) - a project to survey HTTPS security across the entire span of the internet (in usage by [2010](https://www.eff.org/files/defconssliverse.pdf))
- 'data observatory', for instance [this one opened by Imperial College London in 2015](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/data-science/data-observatory/). The term ['data observatory' in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22data+observatory%22) currently returns 124000 results.
- [Croydon Observatory](https://www.croydonobservatory.org/) *"provides access to data and information about Croydon"*
- ['observatory tool'](https://www2.fundsforngos.org/latest-funds-for-ngos/mozilla-technology-fund-auditing-tools-for-ai-systems/) - *"An observatory tool that allows journalists to write stories about what content is promoted or suppressed on a social media platform."*
- [Ethiopia Peace Observatory (EPO)](https://epo.acleddata.com/) - *"local data collection and analysis on political violence and protest trends across Ethiopia"*

These observatories are observing technical, corporate, social, political data, not 'natural' phenomena, so they're not well covered by definition 1), and definition 2) only very-loosely conveys what these newer observatories are like.

So, my question is: "What would be a better definition of 'Observatory' that includes these modern usages?"

As an example, in the comments, Greybeard suggested: *"An observatory is a place from which observations (about anything) are made. It can even be abstract."*

Comment: I don’t offer this as a general answer, but in some circumstances I see the word “Centre” (American “Center”) used in this way.

Comment: "Something that observes"

Comment: I suppose 'overlook' and 'watchtower' have too much baggage.

Comment: These are all simply metaphorical uses of the term. The dictionary compilers just haven't decided that this use is common enough to be a new definition.

Comment: OP is asking for a definition for "observatory" that includes the provided example usage. OP is not satisfied with dictionary given definitions. The question can be restated  as  "How to broaden the definition of observatory to include the example usage?". The supplementary question that would follow from OP's question would be "How to include the new definition in dictionaries?". At least that is what I understood from OP's question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is based upon one dictionary entry that has been assumed to be universally true and infallible: it is not. -- An observatory is a place from which observations (about anything) are made. It can even be abstract.

Comment: ...  [a] monitor

Comment: Why should it have only one definition? Lots of words have multiple related definitions in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another word "**watch**"

It includes all the definitions you are looking for in the examples provided. This link to [Merriam-Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/watch) has all the definitions listed and the list is too long to be posted here.

Supposing, that you want to broaden the definitions of "**observatory**" provided in the dictionaries to include the example usage above, if you are not a dictionary editor in one of the major English dictionaries, I do not know how you would go about that.

Comment: Thanks banuyayi! I'm not specifically interested in how to include a new definition in dictionaries, though obviously that would be very cool. I'm more trying to figure out - if I was trying to define 'observatory' for a person, what definition could I give that would include those usages of 'observatory' included in the question description?